# How to get content search result in Sitecore?

Tags: content-search

I have a droplist field value and based on this value would like to get result from Solr search provide.

Could someone assist me on this ?

Comment: Could you please add some more details about it? What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: Would like to get result based on droplist field value in solr . Do u need any other information ?

Comment: Are you using SXA?  or do you want to get results with the Sitecore Content Search API?

Comment: Yes,  I am using Sxa n would like to get result through content search api through droplist value.

Comment: Use the SXA search filter components https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/102/sitecore-experience-accelerator/use-the-sxa-search-filter-components.html

Comment: Thanks but I am not using Sitecore 10.2 version ?

Comment: Can you please your raw value?

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you want to achieve is to get the data from `Solr` on the basis of a value that you get from a `droplist` field. So I will suggest you to use Sitecore `Content Search` API.

I think you need to refer this article to implement Content Search

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2017/06/09/sitecore-contentsearch-get-items-from-solr-or-lucene-a-base-class-implementation/

What you need to do is to create your query and then pass your ID that you get from a `droplist` field and you will get the result.

Thanks

Comment: I am usng content search api , problem I am facing that I am not able to get result from droplist as the row value of it is string in content editor

Comment: can't you change it into droplink?